# Generate character count of sequences

Tags: python, string

I have a string like '**....(((...((...**' for which I have to generate another string '**ss(4)h5(3)ss(3)h2(2)ss(3)**'.

'.' corresponds to 'ss' and the number of continous '.' is in the bracket.

'(' corresponds to 'h5' and the number of continuos '(' is in the bracket.

Currently I'm able to get the output '**ss(4)h5(3)ss(3)**' and my code ignores the last two character sequences.
This is what I have done so far

```
def main():
    stringInput = raw_input("Enter the string:")
    ssCount = 0
    h5Count = 0
    finalString = ""
    ssString = ""
    h5String = ""
    ssCont = True
    h5Cont = True
    for i in range(0, len(stringInput), 1):
        if stringInput[i] == ".":
            h5Cont = False
            if ssCont:
                ssCount = ssCount + 1
                ssString = "ss(" + str(ssCount) + ")"
                ssCont = True
            else:
                finalString = finalString + ssString
                ssCont = True
                ssCount = 1
        elif stringInput[i] == "(":
            ssCont = False
            if h5Cont:
                h5Count = h5Count + 1
                h5String = "h5(" + str(h5Count) + ")"
                h5Cont = True
            else:
                finalString = finalString + h5String
                h5Cont = True
                h5Count = 1

    print finalString
main()
```

How to modify the code to get the desired output?

Comment: Good effort - can I ask if you're stuck with approaching the problem this way due to it being an assignment of some sort or are you open to other more Pythonic options?

Comment: @JonClements I'm open to any pythonic options. I just want to get the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t know about modifying your existing code, but to me this can be done very succinctly and pythonically using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Note that I’m not sure if the `'h2'` in your expected output is a typo or if it should be `'h5'`, which I’m assuming.

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

string = '....(((...((...'

def character_count(S, labels): # this allows you to customize the labels you want to use
    for K, G in groupby(S):
        yield labels[K], '(', str(sum(1 for c in G)), ')' # sum() counts the number of items in the iterator G

output = ''.join(chain.from_iterable(character_count(string, {'.': 'ss', '(': 'h5'}))) # joins the components into a single string
print(output)

# >>> ss(4)h5(3)ss(3)h5(2)ss(3)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed! :)

Answer (score 1):

@Kelvin 's answer is great, however if you want to define a function yourself, you could do it like this:

```py
def h5ss(x):
    names = {".": "ss", "(": "h5"}
    count = 0
    current = None
    out = ""
    for i in x:
        if i == current:
            count += 1
        else:
            if current is not None:
                out += "{}({})".format(names[current], count)
            count = 1
            current = i
    if current is not None:
        out += "{}({})".format(names[current], count)
    return out
```

Comment: Works welll, really helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: @user5861486 No problem. Btw, the problem in your code is, that you should add the strings for "ss" and "h5" to the output directly, and not just if the next sequence is finished. This is why the last two are missing.